# Task queue concurrency

Tags: algorithm

I have one task queue, and have multiple workers.
To achieve concurrency ,workers insert locked flag to task when get and executing one task.

But here is one problem. 
If one worker kill or pending while locking the task, the task never be executed.
I'm really troubled.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cases where the task performed by the worker is well framed, it is wise to use a **soft mutex**, based on the idea of temporary lock.

Meaning if the task takes approximately 60 seconds for a worker to complete, the worker will lock the task for a safe period of time (say 10 min).
The time when the lock was requested (and locked) is saved as part of the lock.

Every time a worker requests to lock the task, it checks:
If the time now is later than 10 min that the time of the last lock, the worker "steals" the lock and update the time to now.

This creates a mechanism where workers can be killed, and yet not lock the task forever.

Comment: I solved this problem by soft mutex you recommend me

Answer (score 1):

Once a task is about to be locked to a worker, you must use some logic to add a unique identification number to the task that describes itself along with its current worker.

Then you need to employ some polling over each worker in a circular manner i.e, `worker 2` polls over `worker 1`, `worker 3` polls over `worker 2` and `worker 1` polls over `worker 3`.

So, when `worker 1` is down, `worker 2` understands during polling and takes grabs the task of `worker 1`. You also need to maintain a `manager worker`, which takes care of assigning and maintaining a table of tasks mapping to their respective workers.

This is just the basic idea. You also need to take care of things like:

- What if the `manager worker` is down?

Here you must use the `token ring` approach i.e, the worker holding a token is the manager. As soon as the `manager worker` dies, an `election algorithm` must be used to assign a new token to existing workers.